# Is the first X-Men film the only time Jean Grey has been slimed by Toad?

Tags: marvel, x-men, toads-spit

In the first X-Men film, during the Statue of Liberty fight, Cyclops, Wolverine, Jean Grey, and Storm are ambushed by Mystique and Toad, who had both been alerted earlier of the X-Men's arrival. Within less than 5 minutes, Wolverine is stuck fighting Mystique in another section of the Statue, Cyclops is locked in a display case, Storm is locked in an elevator shaft, and Jean is slimed by Toad.

I am curious, however, if the first X-Men film is the only instance of Toad sliming her, or if maybe it was shown again in one of the animated series or comics?

Comment: Worst euphemism ever !

Comment: Not trying to discredit the question, but why are you looking for such a very specific event? Just curious :)

Comment: Found the stack exchange recently, and was intrigued by the 'toads-spit' tag. As for the event in question, I know that certain elements from the film were later incorporated into the comics; New X-Men showed the characters in the black leather, X-Men Forever briefly gave Mystique the blue scales look, and Toad was changed to be more like the Ray Park character. Just wondering if the Toad sliming Jean scene might have also been alluded to at some point.

Comment: I'm going to take a look tonight, I'll get back to this

Comment: As Toad's powerset did not involve saliva until the film and the *X-MEN FOREVER* (2001) miniseries, and as Toad was not an active supervillain at the time, and as Jean died about 2-3 years after the mini-series - probably yes, the only time (unless it happened *in* that mini-series).

Comment: @RDFozz-That sounds like a pretty good answer to me. I believe there are 6, maybe 7 issues in that run, if you wanted to check. Also, at Edlothiad, how is your research going?

Comment: So there's 200 comics to go through, and 21 hours to your bounty ending, while I'm not doing it just for the bounty, it would help me meet certain targets for the year. So expect and answer tonight, sorry I said I would 3 months ago, I got distracted.

Comment: @Edlothiad-Do you still want to answer the question? If so, I can reset the bounty. Just let me know.

Comment: @Edlothiad-Haven't heard from you in a while, was wondering if you made any progress?

Comment: @RDFozz I don't know if you get a notification, but this now has a bounty available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to prove a negative but as far as I can tell Toad only really appears alongside Jean when he is a "good guy" after he has the power to spit and so they don't really fight. They are teamed up in the short 2001 series *X-men Forever* so don't fight. He joins the X-men on other occasions such as joining the Jean Grey School for Higher Learning as the janitor (although of course this particular event is *after* Jean dies).

[image: Toad begs Wolverine for a job]

So barring any explicit evidence that he does slime her at some other stage, which I can't find, I think we have to say the only instance was in *X-Men*.

Comment: Todd was a founding member of the original [Brotherhood of Evil Mutants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brotherhood_of_Mutants) led by Magneto, back when Stan Lee and Jack Kirby conceived of X-Men in the 60s. Cannot recall specifics (had read the stuff as a child), but he and Jean have fought a lot indeed.

Comment: @desertnaut Sure they've fought, my point is _" after he has the power to spit"_ which I believe he didn't always have.

Comment: Fair point. I am not sure about it either

Answer (score 2):

I think that, actually, there is no legit animated series or comic (canon or legend) that details the episode where Toad slimes Jean Grey based on the story by Tom DeSanto and Bryan Singer, and screenplay by David Hayter for the film X-Men (2000). The most elegant and close out-of-canon reference that I have found is a Devianart by artist Lucas Ackerman entitled "Jean Grey vs Toad Final" (2018), but, as the artist Lucas Ackerman says, the mentioned reference is part of separate commissions mashed together in comic form.

[image: Jean Grey vs Toad final_by_lucasackerman]